# Need to take csv file and make a list of the rows in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am brand new to Python and have been thrown into the fire to learn.  I am extremely new and have searched around for the answer, but am having a terrible time understanding what to do.

I need to load in a csv file into Python
There are over 3000 rows with 5 columns. 
I need each row as a list of the columns.

Can someone please show me coding to do this?

Comment: Have you tried [python-pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html)?

Comment: have you tried the csv module? http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: I didn't see anything under Panda that looked like what I wanted.

Comment: I read over the docs but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: I have data that is   11 12 13 14 15
                      21 22 23 24 25

I want to read it into Python and have list
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with what you want then? Both glasslion and I have given you what should be more than enough to deal with csv files.

Comment: Looking at the output, I think I have it right.  If you could answer another question, I would really appreciate it.  Is there a way to create a list within a list?  I have essays as items in the list, and I want to parse the essays

Comment: I have this code 
with open('2011.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
print row

That has everything in lists.  Now the 4th object is an essay that I need created into a list

Comment: You should (for the sake of the community) post what you did into the original post, not as some separate comment. Also, if you have another question you should create another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = """kissa,koira,kana
cat,dog,chicken
neko,inu,niwatori"""

import csv
list(csv.reader(x.splitlines())
```

Result:

```
[['kissa', 'koira', 'kana'], ['cat', 'dog', 'chicken'], ['neko', 'inu', 'niwatori']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your .csv file looks like this, for example:

11,12,13,14,15

21,22,23,24,25

31,32,33,34,35

then this code:

```
\#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('try.csv','r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].strip().split(',')

  print lines[1][2]
```

would print:

```
23
```